# Understanding micro SD cards for camera

Tags: sd-card, camera

I am looking for a micro SD card for my point n shoot camera. I just know that better SD cards have better write/read speed.

I have following questions:

- What do Class-10 and SDHC specify?
- In the picture below, Samsung mentions that the card can be used for Digital Cameras but Scandisk does not say something like that. Does that mean, an SD card may or may not support a Digital Camera?
- I understand that hardware recommendations cannot be asked but I am just wondering where "Toshiba Exceria" card stands in comparison to other cards in the picture below in terms of performance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDHC is the format of SD interface (like SD v2.0). It's capable to provide capacities 2-32GB. For higher capacities there is the SDXC (up to 512 GB). Check what format your camera actually supports.

The Class 10 says that the guaranteed speed is 10MB/s or more. In general it should be sufficient for FullHD 1080p. The Class 10 cards are also marked as UHS Class 1.

Comment: All the manufacturers have mentioned Class-10 in the picture in my question but none of the card displays "10" on it. Either "1" or "3" is written on the cards in the picture above. Any idea, what does that mean?

Comment: The U sign with number in it is the UHS Class sign. So U1 is like Class10 and U3 is much better, as it guarantees 30MB/s.